# Java Applet not working

Tags: 12.04, java, applet, plugins, openjdk

I cant use any Java applets. I installed `icedtea-7-plugin`, and it is even activated under Add-Ons, but if I for example click:

[www.java.com/de/download/testjava.jsp](http://www.java.com/de/download/testjava.jsp)

The test-screen remains grey.

I definitely have a JRE installed--`openjdk-7-jre` and `icedtea-7-plugin` are both installed.

The output of `java -version` is:

```
java version "1.6.0_24"
OpenJDK Runtime Enviroment (IcedTea6 1.11.1) (6b24-1.11.1-4ubuntu3)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.0-b12, mixed mode)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the solution. In my privacy configuration I didn't allow Firefox to accept 3rd party cookies.

I dont have the slightest idea, why that is needed on the official Java site, but now it works!

Comment: I'm having this same exact issue but my FireFox is set up to accept all cookies.